# Как обновить базу при наличии изменений

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

В `asp.net core` это можно делать с помощью миграций и обновлений. 
Добавил в `Global.asx` следующий код, однако он никак не помогает. Единственный вариант который помогает - это удалить базу.

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Включаем *Миграцию* при помощи команды `enable-migrations`;
2. Фиксируем текущее состояние при помощи команды `add-migration`;
3. Применяем изменения к Базе данных при помощи команды `update-database`;

Все команды выполняются в консоли диспетчера пакетов.

более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj591621.aspx)